# Build PHP_CodeSniffer from sources with HHVM

Tags: hhvm, phar

I am trying to use PHP_CodeSniffer in my Hack project. I tried getting the `phpcs.phar` file from the repository and run it, but I get an error, something that seems to be a bug of HHVM (see [#5140](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/5140)). So I tried building it to `.phar` myself. I ran the most obvious script:

```
scripts/build-phar.php
```

so

```
$ hhvm ./scripts/build-phar.php
```

This is the output I get:

```
Building phpcs phar
    => /devel/phpcs/phpcs.phar

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message '/devel/phpcs/phpcs.phar is not a file' in /devel/phpcs/scripts/build-phar.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 /devel/phpcs/scripts/build-phar.php(43): Phar->__construct()
#1 {main}
```

I am not sure where to look or what to look for here. Could you please give me some advice on building a `.phar` from this?